# Set input value in keyup, stops change event from firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

NEW Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/martinnormark/jBZfs/14/ - new isolated example. See how the change event is not fired for Amount 2! **

I have a jQuery plugin for formatting a number in a currency format, as you type.

You can see it in action in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/martinnormark/Rv4Ug/1/

The problem is, if you enter a value of at least 4 digits (causing the need to thousand separator: 1178 becomes 1,178), the change event dies. As long as you stay below 4 digits, not causing a new format, the change event is fired.

In the fiddle, try to enter 12, then 123. You should see a text reading 'change event raised'. And then enter 1234 - and the change event is not fired.

This will have something to do with the manipulation of the input element's value in a keyup event handler:

```
$this.on("keyup.autoformatcurrency", function(event) {
    if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, keyCodes) > -1) {
        formatCurrency($(this), true);
    }
});
```

And the `formatCurrency` function:

```
function formatCurrency($this, setCaretPosition) {

    var rawValue = $this.val(),
        floatValue = Globalize.parseFloat(rawValue);

    if ($.isNumeric(floatValue)) {
        var formattedValue = Globalize.format(floatValue, settings.formatString),
            caretPosition = 0;

        if (setCaretPosition) {
            caretPosition = $this.caret().end + (formattedValue.length - rawValue.length);
        }

        $this.val(formattedValue);

        if (setCaretPosition) {
            $this.caret(caretPosition, caretPosition);
        }
    }

}
```

(for full source, see the file on Github: https://github.com/martinnormark/jquery-format-currency/blob/master/src/jquery.formatcurrency.js )

**The question is**, if there's a way to make sure the change event will be fired?

**UPDATE - Current state in browsers**
**Chrome**: Change event fired, if number is below 4 digits.
**Safari, IE**: Change event is never fired, as long the value is set programmatically. Enter letters instead of numbers will trigger the change event.
**Firefox**: Works!
**Opera**: Works!

Comment: FF 8.0 Win7 : Change event fires even after formatting with a thousands separator (on blur)

Comment: The change event is fired if the text is modified/different when the control lost its focus. so it compare the text that was in the control before gaining focus, with the text that is in the control at losing its focus. If you want you can keep a variable to compare original text and compare at any time in key-up event and predict what you want.

Comment: Seriously? I'm on Win 7, Chrome v16.0.912.59 beta-m. I enter 123, hit tab and the change event is fired. Then i focus the textbox to make the value 1234, which the plugins formats as 1,234. I then hit tab, and the change event is *not* fired...

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem in Chrome and Internet Explorer

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be, to trigger the change event from within the keyup function:

```
$this.on("keyup.autoformatcurrency", function(event) {
    if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, keyCodes) > -1) {
        formatCurrency($(this), true);
        $(this).change();
    }
});
```